# How to access and store selected option value from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm having a lot of trouble. I feel like what I'm trying to do should be dead-simple, yet I cannot figure out what the heck to do.

What I am trying to do is grab whatever value is selected and submitted in my form, and based on that value, show/hide certain tables on the current web page.

```
  <form id="position" method="get">
    <p>Choose your position: </p>
    <select id="position-select" name="positions">
      <option value="utg">UTG</option>
      <option value="utg1">UTG +1</option>
      <option value="utg2">UTG +2</option>
      <option value="lojack">Lowjack</option>
      <option value="hijack">Hijack</option>
      <option value="cutoff">Cutoff</option>
      <option value="button">Button</option>
      <option value="sb">Small Blind</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

I am trying to understand how I can, upon the user selecting one of the dropdown values and then pressing "submit", how can I grab whichever selection they chose and like save it to a variable or something so that I can then show/hide these tables on the page.

I keep reading about the post and get method and like communicating with a server, but I don't even want to do that. I want to basically change the UI of the current web page based on whichever selection they select and submit.

If I can save that value to a variable then I can run something like if (their selected value === xy or z) then show xy or z table and hide the rest of the tables.

Does this make sense? Can anybody help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of a selected option and save it into a variable? (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152303/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-option-and-save-it-into-a-variable-javascri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're trying to use JS to trigger the change i think there's a similar questioned that has been answered:

[How to get the value of a selected option and save it into a variable? (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152303/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-option-and-save-it-into-a-variable-javascri/32152591)

basically, i think you will need to trigger an onChange value for it.

Comment: So if I want to run the function not when they select a value from the list, but rather when they select a value from the list AND THEN press the submit button. So in this case, would I need to instead of doing an onchange, do an onsubmit on the submit button? Is that the same idea?

Comment: Thanks very much--this worked for me. Not sure if I should delete my question because it had already been answered in that post that you linked...Sorry about this. I was researching around for 45+ minutes and did not find that article. Apparently I suck. Anyway cheers thanks, Mark

Comment: i think onSubmit would be submitting the entire form into ur db or wherever youre passing the data to. onChange would just trigger and register the change of value in that particular field/selection. :)